# Error in loading .so file (Tesseract) on real device Android 2.1 

Tags: android, android-ndk, ocr, tesseract

I am developing a sample scan activity for card reading(OCR) using **Tesseract** tools.

It works fine on emulator (using android 2.2) and scans given card from sdcard fastly and easily.
But when I try it on real device or emulator(Using android 2.1) it gives following error:

```
10-13 16:48:59.206: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3086): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.scan/lib/liblept.so 0x2fc14960
10-13 16:48:59.196: DEBUG/SntpClient(1814): request time failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: xtra1.gpsonextra.net
10-13 16:48:59.206: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3086): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.scan/lib/liblept.so 0x2fc14960
10-13 16:48:59.236: INFO/dalvikvm(3086): Unable to dlopen(/data/data/com.scan/lib/liblept.so): Cannot load library: link_image[1829]:  1137 could not load needed library 'libjpeg.so' for 'liblept.so' (load_library[1137]: Library 'libjpeg.so' not found)
10-13 16:48:59.236: WARN/dalvikvm(3086): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown during Lcom/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI;.<clinit>
10-13 16:48:59.236: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3086): Shutting down VM
10-13 16:48:59.236: WARN/dalvikvm(3086): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aaca450)
10-13 16:48:59.236: INFO/dalvikvm(3086): Unable to dlopen(/data/data/com.scan/lib/liblept.so): Cannot load library: link_image[1829]:  1137 could not load needed library 'libjpeg.so' for 'liblept.so' (load_library[1137]: Library 'libjpeg.so' not found)
10-13 16:48:59.236: WARN/dalvikvm(3086): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown during Lcom/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI;.<clinit>
10-13 16:48:59.236: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3086): Shutting down VM
10-13 16:48:59.236: WARN/dalvikvm(3086): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aaca450)
10-13 16:48:59.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-13 16:48:59.246: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at com.scan.SAMPLE_SCANActivity.onCreate(SAMPLE_SCANActivity.java:37)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library lept not found
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:42)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     ... 14 more
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at com.scan.SAMPLE_SCANActivity.onCreate(SAMPLE_SCANActivity.java:37)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library lept not found
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:42)
10-13 16:48:59.256: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3086):     ... 14 more
```

Does this library works on android 2.1 or any other issue???

Comment: it seems could not find or link libjpeg..

Comment: are you sure libjpeg is at this path /data/data/com.scan/lib/libjpeg.so check the file explorer in DDMS and confirm its location

Comment: In your device /data/data/com.scan/lib/liblept.so file exist?

Comment: using adb shell check the file whether exist or not.

Comment: ok, trying to push .so files their using adb push command if it works then resolved the error how to write file to /data directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4231/discussion-between-hanry-and-user370305)

Comment: can you please send source code i have all try but not work in 2.2?

Answer (score 2):

First of all You read all steps:--

For Windows or Ubuntu and to build Android 2.2 app :

1. downloaded the ndk & tesseract tools (svn) project with the README
2. build it on debian(vmware)  with the ndk
3. tesseract tools is actually a library and has a eclipse .project so just import that project after building the so's with ndk and build it.
4. Set it as lib : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject
5. Now in the same workspace create a new android project i.e. your app. Go to properties and reference the library from step 3 (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

**6. Build your app based on Android 2.2 (min) : http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/issues/detail?id=5#c16**

So This library does not works on android 2.1

**[Does this library works on android 2.1 ???](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/issues/detail?id=5#c21)**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing pure java alternative for OCR:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/?_test=beta

Maybe this could be alternative for you.

Comment: I will try to implement your suggested OCR library but is it possible to works on Android 2.1?

Comment: It is pure java and works even on 1.6   There are applciations in market using this ( search for my name )

Comment: As developer and admin of this project I provide support on mailing lists.  Project has android demos, to:  acquire character samples,  perform recognizer training and perform recognition

Answer (score 0):

no, this native library doesnt support in below Android Version 2.2, as Google also serves this *service* online to over come this

Comment: this answer was down voted but in fact Tesseract 3.+ requires Android 2.2